# Using nohup or setsid in PHP as Fast CGI

Tags: php, shell, fork, command-line-interface

I'm trying to do a potentially long background process in response to an incoming AJAX request, but using `nohup` or `setsid` via `shell_exec` causes the server to fork bomb. We use `suexec` and FastCGI, and when it bombs it took the entire server to a crawl.

```
shell_exec("nohup /home/me/myscript.php");
```

The script doesn't do anything lengthy right now, just outputs to an non-existant file (which never happens, because it blows up first)

Thanks!

Comment: You should definitely ask on serverfault, more experts there. But one thing: you should as a precaution nohup the php interpreter before the script (`nohup /usr/bin/php /home/../script.php`). These kind of utils don't work well on shebang scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I've always seen the warnings at http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php (although you're using `nohup`, I knoẁ) as a warning that forking from webserver processes is not a safe way to go. If a background process needs starting, I'll create a daemon / always running job process which can receive such requests (and hasn't got anything to do with the webserver), which forks/nohups at will.